# The value in drop-down menu changes to default after confirming the selection

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-rc

I am writing a Selenium script in Ruby (As a beginner), wherein I need to change the selection of dropdown menu.

**Functionality to automate**-

1.Change the drop-down selection from a default value. (This dropdown is in an iframe)

2.Press Save button.

3.Handle a popup that confirms the change.

4.Page reloads with the new selection.

I am able to change the selection on UI by using "select(locator, value)". I have already disabled Javascript to handle the popup.

**Issue**-
Now, when I press the 'Save' button, the page reloads with the default value that was set.

**e.g**- Dropdown menu has 4 options-

```
<option value="920">Apple</option>

<option selected="selected" value="1">Mango</option>

<option value="910">BlackBerry</option>

<option value="921">Orange</option>
```

Now, when I change the selection to **Orange**, and then press **Save**, the page reloads but only with option 2 selected.

Please suggest any solution/reason for this and how can it be avoided? I hope I am clear with the question.

Comment: Can you show us your code for the form and the select?

Comment: <select id="mainForm:changeFruit:fruitIdSelection" onblur="setCursorWait();A4J.AJAX.Submit('mainForm',event,{'control':this,'oncomplete':function(request,event,data){resetCursor()},'similarityGroupingId':'mainForm:changeFruit:j_id54','parameters':{'ajaxSingle':'mainForm:changeFruit:fruitIdSelection','mainForm:changeFruit:j_id54':'mainForm:changeFruit:j_id54'} } )" size="1" name="mainForm:changeFruit:fruitIdSelection">

Comment: @Douglas- I am not sure which code are you asking for? Do you mean I should put up the code that I've written for selecting the value and then pressing Save button?

Comment: @Douglas- Do you have any inputs/suggestions?

Comment: Without knowing what application you are testing and how it is constructed, it is hard to give advice on this.

Comment: may be silly qs, but are you able to do this manually?

Comment: I am a n00b so took me a while to figure out the reason...After a lot many tries and googling, I found that I had to use the fire_event(locator, "blur") method! 
If you see the source code I pasted in my previous comment, it has a onblur="xyz" 
So I had to call selenium select(locator) followed by fire_event() method before clicking on Save button.
Hope this reply helps others, because using the Select() method alone was keeping the cursor on dropdown, which didn't trigger the save event for newly selected value! Am glad I was able to solve this :)

Answer (score 0):

The main reason that might be happening is because you disabled the javascript. The script usually fires the postback event which loads the page with the new selected element. You should enable the javascript and handle pop-up using switch_to_alert function and explicitly click the confirmation button like a user would.